# Chronicle Queue exception - 'Unsigned Int 31-bit 3544677295290987316 out of range'

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

using Chronicle-Queue 5.16.16 and see following exception:

`2023-05-17 16:02:38 [Thread-12] WARN - Unsigned Int 31-bit 3544677295290987316 out of range java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsigned Int 31-bit 3544677295290987316 out of range at net.openhft.chronicle.core.Maths.toUInt31(Maths.java:367) at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SCQIndexing.sequenceForPosition(SCQIndexing.java:500) at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SCQIndexing.lastSequenceNumber(SCQIndexing.java:665) at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueStore.lastSequenceNumber(SingleChronicleQueueStore.java:253) at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreAppender.writeHeader(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:387) at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreAppender.openContext(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:402) at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreAppender.writingDocument(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:366) at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreAppender.writingDocument(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:346)`

Did someone have such kind of issue and what could be the reason?

attempted to append messages to chronicle-queue and its failed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file was corrupted.  5.16.16 was released in Sep 2018, and I would highly recommend you upgrade to a more recent version such as 5.23.x